# Edit relationship record field in edit view

Tags: react-admin

There's an Item record with has-many field `priceIds`

```json
{
  "priceIds": [1]
}
```

Price record looks as follows

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "value": 20,
  "currencyId": 123
}
```

The task is to edit the prices fields inline in the edit view of the Item Edit view in react-admin. It should be possible to edit `currencyId` and `value` fields for each of the `price` records.

[image]

The problem is that `ReferenceArrayInput` allows only to select from available records. And nested `SimpleForm`'s don't help either because the `price` records have to be saved on the `item` form submit.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: I suggest you use a `<ReferenceArrayField>` with a custom iterator. The custom iterator will have to use react-final-form's `<Field>` component. I'v never done it but I think that's the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But this approach won't let me edit fields of the referenced records :/ I ended up extending `SimpleForm` component and adding `afterSave()` method which receives the result of the saved resource. In this way, I can create price records for item record that just got created